# Edit value then tab change or leave page show message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to show popup message when user edit any value , i want to give popup prompt. I am following [this](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2008/07/21/when-leaving-page-prompt-the-user-that-changes-have-not-been-saved/) site for the help. Its calling only when i am trying to move to some other page. ii have ajax tab page, and i want to show the popup when some oe move to another tab as well as leave the page. I have tried this :

My script look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PanelClick(sender, e) {
    ConfirmExit();
}

function ActiveTabChanged(sender, e) {
    ConfirmExit();

}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var isDirty = false;
window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmExit;

function InputChanged(control)
   {
      isDirty = true;
   }
function ConfirmExit()
{
   if(isDirty == true){
         return "You have attempted to leave this page. If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
      }
}
```

Any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated.

My design look like this :

```
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ID="Tabs" Height="150px" OnClientActiveTabChanged="ActiveTabChanged">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="Server" ID="Panel1" HeaderText="Tab One">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <br />PAGE ONE -  Sample HTML Content for Tab
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"/>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="Server" ID="Panel2" HeaderText="Tab Two" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                PAGE TWO - Sample HTML Content for Tab
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2"/>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="Server" ID="Panel3" OnClientClick="PanelClick" HeaderText="Tab Three">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <BR /><BR />PAGE THREE - Sample HTML Content for Tab
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4"/>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox5"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.ajax__tab_outer');
  for(var t = 0; t < tabs.length; ++t){ 
    tabs[t].addEventListener('click', ConfirmExit); 
  }
</script>
```

and instead of `window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmExit;`
use `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ConfirmExit);`

or use jquery for cross-browser:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.ajax__tab_outer').on('click', ConfirmExit);
  $(window).on('beforeunload', ConfirmExit);
</script>
```

Comment: Did u changed the default ajaxtoolkit classes? can u post a link?

Comment: yes,  its like ` <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="Server" ID="Panel1"   HeaderText="Tab One" CssClass="ajax__tab_outer">`

Comment: it should work ... tested at http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx and it run with no problems. What error message are you getting?